# Copying one sheet to another workbook along with style using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I am trying to copy a sheet from one workbook into another along with the styles (Cell color and merge)
I am using the below code, it is copying but it is filling the already colored cells with black by default.
I am trying to connect the dots for this issue but unable to. What am i missing ?

Apache poi - 4.1.1
The test1 method calls the SheetUtil (using copysheet method from that)

public class SheetUtil {

```
private static void removeRows(Sheet destSheet) {
    if (null != destSheet) {
        for (int i = destSheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= destSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Row row = destSheet.getRow(i);
            if (null != row) {
                destSheet.removeRow(row);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void addRows(Sheet destSheet, int totalRowCount) {
    if (null != destSheet) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalRowCount; i++) {
            destSheet.createRow(i);
        }
    }
}

static void copyMergedRegion(Sheet srcSheet, Sheet destSheet) {
    for (int i = 0; i < srcSheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
        destSheet.addMergedRegion(srcSheet.getMergedRegion(i));
    }
}

private static void copyCell(Cell srcCell, Cell destCell, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {
    if (styleMap != null) {
        int srcCellHashCode = srcCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
        CellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(srcCellHashCode);
        if (null == newCellStyle) {
            newCellStyle = destCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
            newCellStyle.setAlignment(srcCell.getCellStyle().getAlignment());
            newCellStyle.setBorderBottom(srcCell.getCellStyle().getBorderBottom());
            newCellStyle.setBorderLeft(srcCell.getCellStyle().getBorderLeft());
            newCellStyle.setBorderRight(srcCell.getCellStyle().getBorderRight());
            newCellStyle.setBorderTop(srcCell.getCellStyle().getBorderTop());
            newCellStyle.setDataFormat(srcCell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat());
            newCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(srcCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor());
            newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(srcCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());
            newCellStyle.setFillPattern(srcCell.getCellStyle().getFillPattern());
            newCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(srcCell.getCellStyle().getVerticalAlignment());
            newCellStyle.setWrapText(srcCell.getCellStyle().getWrapText());
            styleMap.put(srcCellHashCode, newCellStyle);
        }
        destCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
    }

    if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
        destCell.setBlank();
    } else if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
        destCell.setCellValue(srcCell.getStringCellValue());
    } else if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
        destCell.setCellValue(srcCell.getNumericCellValue());
    } else if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
        destCell.setCellValue(srcCell.getBooleanCellValue());
    } else if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
        destCell.setCellFormula(srcCell.getCellFormula());
    } else if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.ERROR) {
        destCell.setCellErrorValue(srcCell.getErrorCellValue());
    }
}

private static void copyRow(Row srcRow, Row destRow, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {
    destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
    for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        Cell srcCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
        if (srcCell != null) {
            Cell destCell = destRow.createCell(j);
            copyCell(srcCell, destCell, styleMap);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * Copy a sheet from one workbook to another workbook. 
 * 
 * @param srcSheet
 * @param destSheet
 */
public static void copySheet(Sheet srcSheet, Sheet destSheet) {
    removeRows(destSheet);
    addRows(destSheet, srcSheet.getLastRowNum());
    copyMergedRegion(srcSheet, destSheet);
    Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap = new HashMap<Integer, CellStyle>();
    for (int i = srcSheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= srcSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        Row srcRow = srcSheet.getRow(i);
        if (null == srcRow) {
            destSheet.createRow(i);
        } else {
            Row destRow = destSheet.createRow(i);
            copyRow(srcRow, destRow, styleMap);
        }
    }
  
}

public void test1() {
    try {
        System.out.println(" test1() : " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        File templateFile = new File("C:/poiTest/Template_V2.xlsx");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(templateFile);
        Workbook merWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        Sheet destPdrSheet = merWorkBook.getSheet("PDR");

        File pdrFile = new File("C:/poiTest/P23163.xlsx");
        InputStream pdrInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdrFile);
        Workbook pdrWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(pdrInputStream);
        pdrInputStream.close();
        Sheet srcPdrSheet = pdrWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        SheetUtil.copySheet(srcPdrSheet, destPdrSheet);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        merWorkBook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        merWorkBook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);

        FileOutputStream resultFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/poiTest/outputXLSX1.xlsx"));
        byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(resultFile);
        System.out.println(" test1() : " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SheetUtil obj = new SheetUtil();
    obj.test1();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a main difference between `*.xls` and `*.xlsx` when using cell interior colors. The former binary  `*.xls` only uses indexed colors out of a color palette. The current Office Open XML `*.xlsx` uses RGB colors directly. These colors are not indexed.

`CellStyle` of Apache POI tries to support both. But it lacks the possibility to set RGB colors directly. There is `Color getFillBackgroundColorColor()` and `Color getFillForegroundColorColor()` to get the `Color`s . But there is only `void setFillBackgroundColor(short bg)` and `void setFillForegroundColor(short bg)` to set color indexes. There are no methods to set `Color`s.

If in Office Open XML `*.xlsx` RGB colors are used in cell interior, then there are no indexes. That's why `CellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor()` and `CellStyle.getFillForegroundColor()` return `0` in that case. And `CellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(0)` and `CellStyle.getFillForegroundColor(0)` then set indexed colors having index `0`. This is black.

I don't know a good workaround except giving up using `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` and explicitly using `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel`. `XSSFCellStyle` provides `XSSFColor getFillBackgroundColorColor()` and `XSSFColor getFillForegroundColorColor()` as well as `void setFillBackgroundColor(XSSFColor color)` and `void setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)`. So one should use only this for Office Open XML `*.xlsx` and **not** use the methods which are using indexed colors.

There is already a [bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66052) about this.

Comment: wow, that was quite some good info on how things work. I tried as you suggested above. It got the colors perfectly. Thanks :) But it is not copying the bold style for some reasons. any idea on that as well ? @Axel

Comment: @user110009: Seems not as if you are copying the font settings, do you? `XSSFCellStyle` provides `getFont` and `setFont` too. But the font settings might not be in `CellStyle` only but also in `RichTextString`. That's why you should do `... if (srcCell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) { destCell.setCellValue(srcCell.getRichStringCellValue()); ...`.

Comment: If you grab a nightly build of Apache POI, Axel has kindly fixed this bug :)

Comment: tried `getRichStringCellValue()` but it was not copying the bold style, so I removed the single styles and used `newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(srcCell.getCellStyle());` instead and it worked. Thanks for all the help @Axel